# Ajax Oauth 2.0 access token

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Im trying to create a JSON request and I have the below script, for some reason I don't get a response. Can anyone help with this?

I haver my token but I have no idea where I need to put it?

```
    <script>
    $.ajax(
        'https://data.brightcove.com/analytics-api/videocloud/accounts/867903724001/report/?dimensions=video&format=json', {
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            },
            complete: function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://data.brightcove.com/analytics-api/videocloud/accounts/867903724001/report/?dimensions=video&format=json',
      dataType: 'JSONP',
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            },
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
      },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)   {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                }

    })
```

Change datatype json to jsonp. Since you trying to access cross domain you have to use [jsop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: I can change the data type to JSONP, but where to I put my access token?

Comment: U mentioned in right place. It should in beforesend method.

Comment: my access token looks like this dewfdew8f7dew89d7ew8c798c7ew8c9ew7c98e7698ew6c8ec9ewc8ew.

Where do I put that?

Comment: https://data.brightcove.com/analytics-api/videocloud/accounts/867903724001/report/?dimensions=video&format=json&token=dewfdew8f7dew89d7ew8c798c7ew8c9ew7c98e7698ew6c8ec9ewc8ew

Comment: u have to add it in the url. without adding the access token u wont gen access to brightcove api

Comment: I have tried that but I have to use a client ID and a Secret ID too, do I have to create some headers? if so how would I do that?

Comment: token key should added along the url, to get get access to the api and it will be in particular format. Please gothrough the brightcove doc and implement as mentioned in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script in the html file

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.9.4/qs.js"></script>
```

After requiring this script you can write your own javascript function and it will work.

brightcoveClientId: Pass dynamic brightcove client id.
brightcoveClientSecret: Pass dynamic brightcove secret.

```
      async  function brightCove(params) {
          const config = {
          url: 'https://oauth.brightcove.com/v4/access_token',
          method: 'post',
          data: Qs.stringify({
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            client_id: brightcoveClientId,
            client_secret: brightcoveClientSecret,
          })
        };
        const bearerToken = await axios(config);
        const getPlayableUrl = await axios.get(`https://cms.api.brightcove.com/v1/accounts/${brightcoveAccountId}/videos/${embededCode}/sources`,
          {
            "headers": {
              "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "authorization": `Bearer ${bearerToken.data.access_token}`
            }
          });
        }
```

It is working fine for me.